# How to call ListView SelectionChanged method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following method that is called when ListView item selection is changed:

```
private void SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

.........
}
```

I would like to call this method from some other method. How would I do that?

Comment: do you use `sender` and `e` in your handler?

Comment: Yes, same like in code sample

Comment: @Ivan no I meant in the code (where it says .......)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an event handler. It's fired on UI actions. Calling it directly isn't a great idea. Put a method inside it, and then you can call that method if you need to from other places.

```
private void SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged(object sender,     SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomeStuffOnSelectionChanged();
}

public void DoSomeStuffOnSelectionChanged()
{
    // enter code here
}
```

Comment: My sentiments exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Extract all code from `SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged` handler to other method and call it.

```
private void SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSmth();
}
...
private void OtherMethod()
{
    DoSmth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the paramters of `sender` and `e` are not used, simply call the method directly from any other method.

```
SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged(null, null);
```

Note that you are not firing off an event by calling this method; this is just the event's callback method and can be used by any other method.

---

The advice given in the other answers are just as correct, but are simply syntatic suger for coding paradigms and can be used as preference or styles are dictated.